# Using quantifer elimination with Z3 Python

Tags: z3, z3py

I try to find the values for A,B,C,D  satisfiying the formula `g = And(ForAll([i, j, k], Implies(And(k <= 0, A * i + B * j + C * k + D <= 0), k + i - j <= 0)),Not(And(A==0,B==0,C==0)))`  using `solve(g)`  .  This has many possible solutions, one is `A=1,B=-1,C=D=0` but Z3 can't seem to do this (`solve(g)` does not terminate).

Can Z3 do this kind of nonlinear (but simple) formula ? Perhaps I can specify some QE strategies or something for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Z3 has a quantifier elimination tactic. We can enable it by creating a solver using:

```
s = Then('qe', 'smt').solver()
```

This command will create a solver that first applies quantifier elimination and then invokes a SMT solver. However, Z3 has very limited support for quantifier elimination of nonlinear formulas. Your examples is nonlinear because it contains: `A * i + B * j + C * k + D <= 0`. 
So, the `qe` tactic will not be able to eliminate the quantifier.

It would be great if you could implement better QE support for nonlinear arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, if QE for nonlinear arith is not supported, then why not just have `solve(g)` returns unknown or unsupported when seeing these kind of formulas?  Instead, it appears as it's trying to do something ?  

Also, does Z3 has QE support for nonlinear *equalities*  or any other nonlinear arithmetic class ?  Do you know if any other SMT solver provides support for Non linear arith?   Thanks again

Comment: Z3 uses heuristic instantiation and model based quantifier instantiation. These methods are not complete, but they can solve many problems. Note that, most of the problems (containing quantifiers) sent to Z3 are in a undecidable fragment, but this fact does not prevent Z3 from solving a subset of them.

Comment: As far as I know, Z3 has the best support for nonlinear arithmetic. It is very effective in (quantifier-free) nonlinear arithmetic problems. See comparison in the end of this article http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/IJCAR2012.pdf

Comment: BTW, we can use timeouts to interrupt the execution of Z3. So, we can quantify the amount of time Z3 will spend using the heuristic methods for handling quantifiers.